# Function in Polar Coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polar-coordinates

Let $f,g:I\to\mathbb{R}$ be two function in $C^{k}(I)$, with the property that $f^2(t)+g^2(t)=1, \ \forall\ t\in I$. Is there a function $\theta: I\to\mathbb{R}$, $\theta\in C^{k}(I)$, such that:

$\left\{\begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta(t))=f(t) \\ \sin(\theta(t))=g(t)\end{array}\right.$

?

Note that, $C^{k}(I)$ is the class of all continuous function, having derivative of order $k$ that are continuous on $I$.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by a very slight generalization of the path lifting theorem (PLT). Treat your functions $f$ and $g$ together as a path
$$
\gamma: I \to S^1 : t \mapsto (f(t), g(t))
$$

This lifts, by the PLT, to a map to the universal cover, $\mathbb R$, of $S^1$, 
$$
\tilde{\gamma}: I \to \mathbb R 
$$
with the property that 
$$
p \circ \tilde{\gamma}= \gamma
$$
where $p$ is the universal covering map, 
$$
p: \mathbb R \to S^1 : t \mapsto (\cos(t), \sin(t))
$$

You can then define $\theta(t) = \tilde{\gamma}(t)$.

Now all that's left is to prove differentiability, which is straightforward.

Comment: I wonder if it is posibile in that particular case to find an explicit formula for $\theta (t)$. I need this in solving some differential equations. 

Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer. It helped me.

Comment: Sure, sort of: $\theta(t) \approx atan2(g(t), f(t))$, with the "approx" because you might need to add multiples of $2\pi$ to make it continuous at points where $g(t) = -1$. Alternatively, you could write $\theta(t) = arg(f(t) + {\mathbf i } g(t))$, where "arg" is the multi-valued complex "argument" function. Either one of these is probably sufficient, in the sense that even if $\theta$ is hard to write down, $\theta'(t)$ is relatively easy, because locally $\theta(t) = C + \arctan(g(t)/f(t))$, where $C$ is some multiple of $2\pi$, and for your DE, $\theta'$ may be all that's needed.

Comment: Now I understand. Best wishes!

Comment: I came across another problem. If the functions $f$ and $g$ are analytic on $I$, then so is $\theta$, too?

Comment: I don't know enough about the definition of "analytic" to say with any confidence. I'd bet that it *is*, but that's not a proof. :)

Comment: @Bogdan In this situation yes, $\theta$ is analytic if $f$ and $g$ are, because the covering map is analytic and locally invertible (the derivative of $t\mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$ is nonzero everywhere).